# pyspark write.parquet() creates a folder instead of a parquet file

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I try to write a pyspark dataframe to a parquet like this

```
df.write.parquet("temp.parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

but it creates an empty folder named `temp.parquet` instead of a parquet file. What might cause this problem?

Comment: It is not a problem that is intended.

Comment: It is expected behavior. parquet files will be written inside your `temp.parquet` folder

Comment: @RahulRaut I checked and the folder is empty, how do I find the parquet file then?

Comment: Just to validate , did you tried to visualize the data in the data frame using .show() or collect(). Try using the full path df.write.parquet("/tmp/temp.parquet", mode="overwrite")

Comment: seems your `df` is empty. please check data in df using `df.show()`

Comment: @RahulRaut I checked and the table is not empty. In fact, the table is from another parquet file, I want to add a new column to that table and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded hadoop.dll from [here](https://github.com/4ttty/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-3.0.0/bin/hadoop.dll) and add it to System32 folder and it solved the problem.

Comment: This worked for me, can you explain what this did and how it works?